# Does DynamoDB support aggregate functions like AVG, MAX, MIN?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I tried DynamoDB docs and work with example using `QueryResult`, I couldn't find any source how to using min, max and avg in DynamoDB (I'm using Java API).

Answer (score 11):

These are not provided. You'd implement these by either doing a query or scan with a filter, and calculating the values yourself.  To simplify things a bit, you can use the [`Count` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Count) to return only the count of items that would be returned by that query/scan instead of the actual items. (Note that count only returns a partial count - you may need to sum counts across multiple pages of queries/scans).

Alternatively, you can maintain a separate table that stores these values for you as the main tables are updated (note this can be tricky to keep in sync, you'll have to use some form of transaction management and take into account dynamo's eventual consistency model).

Comment: Only count is supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Count

Comment: Not quite - count only returns partial results from that query - you still need to assemble the total count yourself.  I've copy and pasted the relevant doc notes from your link here: "*If the matching items for a filter expression or query condition is over 1 MB, Count contains a partial count of the total number of items that match the request. To get the full count of items that match, take the LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request, and use that value as the ExclusiveStartKey in the next request. Repeat this until DynamoDB no longer returns a LastEvaluatedKey.*"

Comment: You're right, you might have to sum all partial counts to get the total count. But still it's more efficient than retrieving the individual items and counting them in the application side. Of course this would only work for counts and not for any other aggregate function.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify this. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem like you, and then I got 2 ideas to solve that problem. 
1st one - is to query all data using query/scan then aggregate your data in the java code. 
2nd one - is to use Hive SQL, you can use Hive and DyanmoDB together, and aggregate your data in Hivql.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.html