# how to find min max avg from dynamo db

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am working in plotting the graph from dynamodb data.I need to plot max min avg of dynamo db records.
Example:-

```
[{
 Time:"yyyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec",
 key:value
 },
{
Time:"yyyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec",
key:value
}]
```

Help to find the max,min,avg of key based on Date String

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does DynamoDB support aggregate functions like AVG, MAX, MIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298829/does-dynamodb-support-aggregate-functions-like-avg-max-min)

Comment: Have you defined the time attribute as sort key of the table ?